# aiogevent event loop "fails" to track greenlets

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, gevent

I recently stumbled onto a problem of mixing up gevent and asyncio-based code, because some synchronous libraries work just fine when I monkey-patch them with `gevent.monkey.patch_all()`. I found the `aiogevent` library, which seems to help by implementing the PEP 3156, and replace asyncio event loop with another implementation of your choice (in this case it's gevent). Last significant commits to git repository I found was made 4 years ago. After fixing setup.py, I managed to successfully install it, but problem is that it doesn't pass all the test.

One of those tests is [test_soon](https://github.com/MaxLunar/aiogevent/blob/master/tests/test_gevent.py#L125), which spawns greenlet that should do operation and stop the loop. This test hangs forever, because `loop.stop()` doesn't have any effect on the loop, which is expected to stop when all tasks are finished. I wrote two snippets to check if it happens with traditional coroutines, and another with greenlets via `gevent.spawn`.

```
import gevent
import aiogevent
import asyncio

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(aiogevent.EventLoopPolicy())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def func():
    print('bloop')
    loop.stop()

loop.create_task(func())
loop.run_forever() # works alright and stops as soon as func finish
```

And with `gevent.spawn`:

```
import gevent
import aiogevent
import asyncio

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(aiogevent.EventLoopPolicy())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def func():
    print('bloop')
    loop.stop()

g = gevent.spawn(func)
loop.run_forever() # func is executed as soon as loop runs, but loop.stop() is ignored
```

And the question: what could possibly go wrong here? I clearly see that greenlet runs after I start the loop, but it is "untracked" by the loop? I can't find the exact line in asyncio sources which corresponds to this mechanism, and the same for gevent - I'm not quite familiar with internals of those modules and searching through them is confusing, but I want to know what is different and what changes to `aiogevent`'s event loop must be done in order to pass the tests.

**upd1**: to emphasize the problem, `gevent.hub.Hub` doesn't have "public" handles to stop the loop, only those that should destroy it completely (`gevent.hub.get_hub().destroy()` currently has no effect, and trying to join the hub greenlet fails if not called within MAIN greenlet). It does have internal exception that is raised somewhere when loop exits (`gevent.exceptions.LoopExit`). My thought was to find the way of how to catch this exception, and tie it with run_forever, but no results yet.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a guess at this, but I think you're using the event loop wrong for asyncio. *I don't know enough about gevent to understand what type of object it's creating to know if this will work.* The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) would indicate that the order in which stop() and run_forever() are called is relevant to the operational call stack, reading as follows:

> If stop() is called before run_forever() is called, the loop will poll the I/O selector once with a timeout of zero, run all callbacks scheduled in response to I/O events (and those that were already scheduled), and then exit.

> If stop() is called while run_forever() is running, the loop will run the current batch of callbacks and then exit. Note that new callbacks scheduled by callbacks will not run in this case; instead, they will run the next time run_forever() or run_until_complete() is called.

I'm assuming that this option is being used to control the status of the asynchronous event, but you may find that `run_until_complete()` may be the better option for you and it may be something like this:

```
import gevent
import aiogevent
import asyncio

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(aiogevent.EventLoopPolicy())

loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

async def func():
    await print('bloop') # await keyword not needed, just demonstrating
    loop.stop()

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(gevent.spawn(func))
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
```

**I added `shutdown_asyncgens()` incase you are awaiting a yield response which would cause the `close()` method to hang/fail.** I don't have any of these installed to test with, so let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Interesting. So technically, I'm safe to drop-in the aiogevent in its current form into projects if I add the greenlets as you shown? Can you help me to fix tests if possible? I'll try to make some research too and maintain project, I just dont have enough understanding of the internals yet.

Comment: Technically, if I explicitly pass the greenlets to the `run_until complete`, it should work, but I'm not sure about those which created without knowing about asyncio in the current program. I thinked about removing some tests and adding new, but I might be wrong. All I need is to be able to stitch two different pieces of code which use asyncio and gevent, and make sure theyre both scheduled by the same eventloop provided by aiogevent, all the awaits etc. I could create an issue and continue the conversation there if you wish to help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just use a while loop like this:

```
from time import sleep
while(1 == 1):
  print('bloop')
  sleep(1)
```

This will print bloop wait one second then print it again (because 1 = 1), please forgive me if I'm wrong, and you have to use the function you were using, but I gave it my best shot.

Comment: So you think OP just wanted to print bloop every 1 second, but overthought about it and thought it was useful to use event loops?

Comment: The problem isn't about printing bloops. I just provided minimal code that shows the problem.